# import psycopg2 image not found

Tags: python, postgresql, pip, psycopg2

```
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-bd284aa2cf56> in <module>()
----> 1 import psycopg2

/Users/gwulfs/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/__init__.py in <module>()
     48 # Import the DBAPI-2.0 stuff into top-level module.
     49
---> 50 from psycopg2._psycopg import BINARY, NUMBER, STRING, DATETIME, ROWID
     51
     52 from psycopg2._psycopg import Binary, Date, Time, Timestamp

ImportError: dlopen(/Users/gwulfs/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so, 2): Library not loaded: libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/gwulfs/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/psycopg2/_psycopg.so
  Reason: image not found
```

Comment: Can you add the piece of code which throws up the error trace and a general description of your problem? otherwise, this question is off topic.

Comment: I ran:
import psycopg2